# Booting to a black screen with a blinking cursor

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, 19.10

I've just installed Ubuntu 19.10 on a [Lenovo ThinkStation P330](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/think-workstations/thinkstation-p-series-towers/ThinkStation-P330-Tower/p/WMD00000364) and I'm having problems to load Ubuntu. It has Windows 10 installed and I wanted to have dual boot.

I did a *manual* install, because since I have two hard drives, I wanted to have the system in one an the home folder in the other one.

I created a partition using Windows in the disk with the windows system to install Ubuntu. Then I proceed to install Ubuntu using an USB Stick.

On the installing screen I've selected "something else" and them I set the new created partition as root `/` and format it on ext4. In other disk I created a partition for the home folder.

GRUB seems to work properly and the option ubuntu seems to be pointing to the right disk. If I select Ubuntu in GRUB I end up in the back screen with the cursor blinking forever.

However, if I select other options for ubuntu in GRUB, and select "recovery mode" for ubuntu, the system it's able to boot normally after the recovery mode. And I mean after the recovery mode when I just reach that and hit enter to "continue booting normally". Then it goes to the black screen and after some time with the blinking cursor it finally load the system.

Does anyone has the slightest idea of what is going on?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the problem was the secure boot that was activated in the bios and it was the first time I was dealing with it, so I didn't know how to handle it. I would say that it isn't really intuitive the thing.

I finally disabled it on the BIOS and everything is correct now.